# Como criar configurações via json no codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Como usar um arquivo de configurações em json, de modo que os valores dos parâmetros dos arquivos tornem-se variáveis de configurações estilo $config['var'] no codeigniter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente é necessário criar um arquivo json, neste caso, deixei com o nome 'config.json' e coloquei na raiz do meu projeto.

> estrutura do arquivo:

```
{
 "conf": 
 {
    "empresa": "Nome da empresa",
    "default_email" : "contato@empresa.com.br",
    "system_email" : "sistema@empresa.com.br"
 }
}
```

Agora basta editar o arquivo config.php do codeigniter, localizado na pasta config, adicionando o sequinte código ao final do arquivo:

```
//configs especificas do json de configuracao
if (file_exists(FCPATH."config.json"))
{   
   //nesse caso está em FCPATH."config.json"
   //mas é possível alterar o caminho de acordo com a sua necessidade.
   $json = file_get_contents(FCPATH."config.json",0,null,null);  
   $j = json_decode($json);
   foreach ($j->conf as $key => $value) 
   {
     $config[$key] = $value;
   }
}
```

Após isso as variáveis criadas no json já estarão disponíveis para serem usadas como configurações do codeigniter, por exemplo, para usar o valor de "empresa" do meu json dentro do Codeigniter, é necessário usar `$this->config->item('empresa');`